# How can i make apk with target version lower than 26(oreo) in android studio3?

Tags: android

We use private app store, so we can upload app which is lower than 26 target sdk.
How can i build apk with target version lower than 26(oreo)?

Android studio 3.3 show build release error.
It says i should use target sdk 26 or higher.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. At minimum, provide the build error logs from Android Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have added following line above line of target sdk line in the build.gradle

```
//noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
```

It allows me to release apk which target sdk is lower than 26 sdk.
It looks likes being able to ignore lint error.

Comment: note, it will allow to build release apk, if target is 22. It still fails, if you try to target 14.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a lower version of Gradle in your project-level build.gradle file. For instance, for Android N try using:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.14.1'
```